# How can I use return instead of let in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/weatherapp/data/db/ForecastDb.kt

I hope to use **return** instead of **let**, so I write the Code B, but the Code B can't be compiled, and I get two errors, why?

Error:(30, 10) 'return' is not allowed here

Error:(30, 45) Type mismatch: inferred type is CityForecast? but CityForecast was expected

**The Code A**

```
 override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

        val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
        val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
                .parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }

        val city = select(CityForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple("${CityForecastTable.ID} = ?", zipCode.toString())
                .parseOpt { CityForecast(HashMap(it), dailyForecast) }

        city?.let { dataMapper.convertToDomain(it) }
    }
```

**The Code B**

```
 override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

        val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
        val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
                .parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }

        val city = select(CityForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple("${CityForecastTable.ID} = ?", zipCode.toString())
                .parseOpt { CityForecast(HashMap(it), dailyForecast) }

        return  dataMapper.convertToDomain(city)
    }
```

Comment: You may not return from a closure. The last expression of the closure is the implicitly returned value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`convertToDomain` is expecting an non-null `CityForecast` instead of nullable `CityForecast?`. So, using `let` is a better approach. Otherwise, you have to force unwrap the nullable `city` like this:

```
dataMapper.convertToDomain(city!!)
```

Beside, you have to use [qualified returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) if you want to return from a lambda:

```
return@use dataMapper.convertToDomain(city!!)
```